# color image clipping after color correction

Tags: python, colors

I used a color checker image -24 to calculate color correction matrix. I used the colour-science package in Python. First, I extract the card image with colour_checker_detection module (detect_colour_checkers_segmentation). I then used the 24 colour swatches along with colour.CCS_COLOURCHECKERS['ColorChecker24 - After November 2014'] to calculate colour corrected checker card image. I have done the cctf_decoding and cctf_encoding before and after performing colour correction. For Cheung_2004 with 3 terms, there is no apparent clipping, but it becomes serious matter when applying Cheung_2004 20 terms. So is the Finalyson_2015, but not as bad as Cheung_2004 with 20 terms. [![most of the swatches displayed certain amount of clipping][1]][1]
the original image was captured with no saturation and white balanced.

My question is how to minimize such clipping effect on colour correction images? Did I miss a step? Is there anything that I did wrong or the images were not ideal to work with?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z726s.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to confirm without seeing the original data but as you use higher order functions, you will also be fitting better the noise in your image.

The image you sent seems to exhibit quite a bit of it, I would recommend to either denoise it or average multiple images, i.e. stacking.

Something important to also consider Is that higher order functions tend to behave very well in the training dataset but they are subject to explosions outside of it, i.e. high order polynomials do not extrapolate well.

Comment: Instead of working on correcting original data, I tried to create color checker images using colour.characterisation.ColourChecker() command. while trying to plot multiple newly created colour checker images in one matplotlib figure with subplots, I can only create one colour checker images in one of the subplots by following examples in https://github.com/colour-science/colour/issues/199. It seems that plot_single_colour_checker" only allows one colour checker to be drawn in one of the subplots. Any suggestions? @ Kel Solaar

Comment: This would be better suited in separate question but each plotting function should return a `figure` and `axes` and also take `axes` and `standalone` kwargs, this should allow you to create sub-plots, pass the `axes` to the `plot_single_colour_checker` whilst also passing `standalone=False`.